# "TypeError: X is not a function" in scalatest test

Tags: scala.js

I'm writing a scala.js test using scalatest in which I need to create an XMLHttpRequest object.  I get the following error and can't figure out why.

`[info]   scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: TypeError: $g.XMLHttpRequest is not a function`

I've reduced the failing test down to:

```
package oat.browser.network

import org.scalajs.dom.XMLHttpRequest
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec

class AjaxToolsSpec extends FreeSpec {

  "AjaxTools" - {
    "should parse a simple object" in {
      val xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()   // Failing line
      this.succeed
    }
  }
}
```

I've successfully included the line 
`val xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()` in my main program and that works fine.

So what's weird about the test environment that causes this?

build.sbt contains
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(..., "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.1",...)`

Comment: I suspect it's down to your test environment -- most JS test environments don't include the DOM by default.  I believe that would explain your error.  The libraryDependencies entry tells Scala.js to *expect* that XMLHttpRequest is there, but that doesn't help if it really doesn't exist in the environment you're executing in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [configure a JavaScript environment](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/js-environments.html) that supports the DOM, for example with this sbt setting:

```
jsEnv := new org.scalajs.jsenv.jsdomnodejs.JSDOMNodeJSEnv()
```

which requires you to install `jsdom` separately (typically with `npm install jsdom`).

Comment: Wow!  What a fast response (26 minutes).  Thanks!  But I'm still struggling.  At first jsdomnodejs wasn't defined in package jsenv.  Bumped the version of sbt-scalajs from 0.6.17 to 0.6.19.  No change.  Added "jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM" to the settings for the module in question.  Then got

[error] /Users/bwbecker/oat/src/oat3/node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:10
[error] const { URL } = require("whatwg-url");
[error]       ^
[error] 
[error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

That's in the jsdom library that got installed with "npm install jsdom".

Comment: Your version of Node.js is too old. You need at least version 6 for jsdom to work IIRC.

Comment: The fast optimization phase of running tests takes much longer than it used to.  Is it reasonable to assume that it's due to including the jsdom in the optimizations?  Is there a way to segregate tests to avoid this? Seems like putting those tests into a separate module would do it, but that may be overkill.

Comment: It does not include jsdom, no. Tests are *already* in their own "module" (configuration, really), so I'm not sure what else you want. It is probably not the fast optimization phase that takes longer; it's the startup time under jsdom versus non-jsdom. You think fast optimization is to blame because nothing is printed on the console between the *beginning* of fastOpt, and the first completed test run. But there is nothing that shows when the *end* of fast opt happens. For that you have to look at `last` or enable the `debug` log level.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.